# phoenix pass variable to view

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

i have a query result that will be used in view, but when i call the variable in view, i got `undefined function data/0` (because data is not function)

i already pass data with different way, map, etc

controller.ex :

```
def new(conn, _params) do
    data =
        Enum.map(
          from(AccountTypeSchema)
          |> Repo.all(),
          fn elem ->
            elem |> Map.from_struct() |> Map.delete(:__meta__)
          end
        )
    render(conn, "new.html", data: data)
end
```

view.html.eex :

```
<% Enum.each data, fn(item) -> %>
    <option value="us">Facebook</option>
<% end %>
```

call `data` variable from view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this code instead:

```
render(conn, "new.html", account_types: data)
```

Then in view:

```
<% Enum.each @account_types, fn(item) -> %>
  <option value="us">Facebook</option>
<% end %>
```

Generally you have `@` prefixed variables available in template when you pass keyword list or map to a view: https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix/Phoenix.View.html#render/3

Comment: One does not need to prefix a variable with `@` to make it available in templates AFAICT.

Comment: Other way round: pass a keyword list to template, access variables with `@`.

Comment: `foo: :bar` as the last parameter is _already_ a keyword list. Why do you think `@` is mandatory? Am I missing something?

Comment: Oh, now I see error in my answer: I prefixed account_types with `@`. Fixed. Thanks for comment!

Comment: yeah, i missed @ in template

Answer (score 1):

`Enum.map/2` returns a list (I took a responsibility to rewrite the code in more idiomatic way):

```
data =
  AccountTypeSchema
  |> Repo.all()
  |> Enum.map(& &1 |> Map.from_struct() |> Map.delete(:__meta__))
```

Obviously one cannot access list by key; pass a keyword instead:

```
render(conn, "new.html", data: data)
```

Comment: `<% Enum.each @data, fn(item) -> %>
        <option value="<%= item.key %>"><%= item.name %></option>
    <% end %>`

weird, <option> not printed in html

Comment: Are you sure your `AccountType` has keys `key` and `value`?!

Comment: i'm sure, there is no error, just <option> not printed in html

Comment: What `Repo.all(AccountTypeSchema)` returns in say `iex`?

Comment: Well, try `<%= inspect(@data) %>` and see what is there.

Comment: So, `@data` is there and it’s fine (although I doubt `IO.puts(@data)` could ever produce this output.) The issue is somewhere else then..

Comment: https://elixirforum.com/t/html-tag-inside-enum-each-not-printed/19001/2